# Format Powershell Command

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

To Start my command

```
Get-Clustergroup | ? { $_.groupType -eq "VirtualMachine" }
```

which returns

```
Name            OwnerNode    State
----            ---------    -----

TESTBED         NODE1        Online  
MACHINE01       NODE1        Online
```

So I run the following command to return only values and strip white space and empty lines.

```
Get-Clustergroup | ? { $_.groupType -eq "VirtualMachine" } | foreach { $_Name }
```

Which returns the machine names as expected,

```
TESTBED
MACHINE01
```

I have an issue because I also want to pull out the Status (State) of that machine. I have tried.

```
Get-Clustergroup | ? { $_.groupType -eq "VirtualMachine" } | foreach { $_Name,$_State }
```

but this does not return the status also just the name still. I wanted to be able to retrieve something like.

```
TESTBED,Online
MACHINE01,Online
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a format string:

```
$timeframe = (get-date).AddMinutes(-80)
$log | ? { $_.failures -like '*Denied*' -or $_.failures -like '*error*'  -and [datetime]$_.'date-time' -ge $timeframe }

Get-Clustergroup | ? { $_.groupType -eq "VirtualMachine" } | foreach { '{0},{1}' -f $_.Name,$_.State }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Get-ClusterGroup |
    Where-Object  { $_.groupType -eq "VirtualMachine" } |
    Select-Object Name, State
```

To query the properties you need and return them as objects to the command line, which will then be displayed as:

```
Name            State
----            -----
TESTBED         Online  
MACHINE01       Online
```

Or, you can use

```
Get-ClusterGroup |
    Where-Object   { $_.groupType -eq 'VirtualMachine' } |
    ForEach-Object { '{0},{1}' -f $_.Name, $_.State }
```

To return the string values exactly as you requested:

```
TESTBED,Online  
MACHINE01,Online
```

Comment: I also want to strip whitespace and headers.

Comment: You does not need backtick ` here since `|` already requires additional operand.

Comment: No. You does not need backtick in .ps1 file. PowerShell applies same rules to command line and to script file.

Comment: Thank you very much, I can now use this with a regular expression to send the results to a database which I can then use for a dashboard.

Comment: I run this command via a vb.net console application, Is there anyway i can remove the " and make them ' as i cannot use " in a invoke command.

Comment: @Matt using single quotes will prevent `PowerShell` from evaluating the string contents. You might be able to use `%{ Write-Host $_.Name','$_.State }` instead, but then you will get an extra space around the comma. Otherwise you will need to use a format string instead, as the other (deleted) answer suggested.

Comment: Get-Clustergroup | ? { $_.groupType -eq 'VirtualMachine' } | foreach { '{0},{1},{2}' -f $_.Name,$_.State,$_.OwnerNode } - Thanks for all your help with this.

Comment: @Matt i would by the way highly recommend seeking support for double quotes in your console app, since that will come handy in much more places...